# Filed for a patent, then wrote a research paper about it: should the paper cite the patent?

Tags: publications, citations, patents

I filed for a patent, then wrote a research paper about the same idea. Should the paper cite the patent?

Comment: Related question: [Why patents are not cited in papers as that of journal papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79572/546)